# want to swap wordpress colour scheme per category

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a twenty-seventeen child theme, which i want to switch colour scheme per category, (from colors-custom to colors-dark - eventally it will have more color schemes)

but this isn't working

```
add_filter( 'body_class', function( $classes ) {
if ( is_category( 'x cateorgy' ) ) 
{ 
    foreach($classes as $key => $class) {
        if( $class == "colors-custom" )
    {
                unset($classes[$key]);
        }
    }
}
$classes[] = 'colors-dark';
return $classes;
}, 1000);
```

I've initially tried it with out the first conditional if (is category()) and it adds color-dark but the css doesn't change.

Comment: ahh i think need to enqueue the colors-dark.css file after

Answer (score 0):

Simply target the body element css classes for specific categories. The twenty seventeen theme uses the body_class() function and outputs class names for everything.

Just write css styles for background colors for every category class.